# Is there a way to sort files by svn status in Windows 10 explorer?

Tags: windows, svn, windows-10, tortoisesvn, explorer

Is there a way to sort files by svn status in Windows 10 explorer?

I'm using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: why don't you use check for modifications dialog of TSVN shell extension? here you can sort by status (added, modified, deleted)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Microsoft removed custom columns from Explorer a couple of releases ago, and that's the only way you'd be able to do this definitively.

Like @magicandre1981 said, you can use TSVN's Check for Modifications dialog, or sort by Date Modified in Explorer (as the most recently edited ones will likely be ones you've edited locally & haven't committed yet).

Answer (score 0):

A hack you could do is update the last modified date of all files not under version control to *now*, then sorting by *Date modified* would yield first all files not under version control.

**Do not do that if losing the actual last modified date is a problem.**

Unix command to do that (works in Git for Windows):

`svn status|sed 's:\\:/:g'|grep '^?'|awk '{print $2}'|xargs -n1 touch`

This command only allow you to split between versioned and not versioned files, to actually sort by status you could try to replace `grep '^?'` by `sort`. Warning: all files will have their *last modified date* changed. That may not work if the last modified date precision is not enough, in which case you would have to add a millisecond delay in the xargs command.